# mapbox studio Source Locked

Tags: mapbox

I start a new style project and choose Mapbox Dark V1. When I look in the 'layers' tab, it says 'Source Locked (custom layer order)'.

How do I add my own custom data to this map? I want to follow the tutorial but I can't get past this point.

Answer (score 0):

If the style project's `project.yml` file has layer order manually defined, then adding new sources from within the app is disabled.  If you save the project, and open the `project_name.tm2/project.yml` file, you'll see something like:

```
attribution: Map data © OpenStreetMap contributors
bounds: 
  - -180
  - -85.0511
  - 180
  - 85.0511
center: 
  - 31.0364
  - 2.2756
  - 11
layers: 
  - landcover
  - hillshade
  - contour
  - moreLayers...
maxzoom: 22
minzoom: 0
name: Map Name
source: "mapbox:///mapbox.mapbox-terrain-v2,mapbox.mapbox-streets-v5,crowdcover.efad3d99"
styles: 
  - style.mss
  - water.mss
  - terrain.mss
  - road.mss
```

If you want to be able to edit the source from w/i the app, set `layers: null`, though this will throw off your style.  More likely it's easier to just manually add the source id to end of the `source:` key, making sure it's comma delimited w/ no space.

#### edit

there's some official documentation on this on the [MapBox Studio Classic](https://www.mapbox.com/help/style-manual/#custom-layer-order) page.

It's a shame there's not an easier method for editing sources from w/i the app.